# Map json data into dart class then put into flutter listview

Tags: json, api, flutter

Its my first time working with apis, but the json that I am receiving is quite big and complicated, so the scenario is as follows:

1. I have a json data that is retrieved from an api
2. The data in the json must be displayed in a listview in flutter
3. I created a class to map the data:

```
class Anime {
  int malId;
  String url;
  String title;
  String imageUrl;
  String synopsis;
  String type;
  String airingStart;
  Null episodes;
  int members;
  List<Genres> genres;
  String source;
  List<Producers> producers;
  double score;
  List<String> licensors;
  bool r18;
  bool kids;
  bool continuing;

  Anime(
      this.malId,
      this.url,
      this.title,
      this.imageUrl,
      this.synopsis,
      this.type,
      this.airingStart,
      this.episodes,
      this.members,
      this.genres,
      this.source,
      this.producers,
      this.score,
      this.licensors,
      this.r18,
      this.kids,
      this.continuing);

  Anime.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    malId = json['mal_id'];
    url = json['url'];
    title = json['title'];
    imageUrl = json['image_url'];
    synopsis = json['synopsis'];
    type = json['type'];
    airingStart = json['airing_start'];
    episodes = json['episodes'];
    members = json['members'];
    if (json['genres'] != null) {
      genres = new List<Genres>();
      json['genres'].forEach((v) {
        genres.add(new Genres.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    source = json['source'];
    if (json['producers'] != null) {
      producers = new List<Producers>();
      json['producers'].forEach((v) {
        producers.add(new Producers.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    score = json['score'];
    licensors = json['licensors'].cast<String>();
    r18 = json['r18'];
    kids = json['kids'];
    continuing = json['continuing'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['mal_id'] = this.malId;
    data['url'] = this.url;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['image_url'] = this.imageUrl;
    data['synopsis'] = this.synopsis;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['airing_start'] = this.airingStart;
    data['episodes'] = this.episodes;
    data['members'] = this.members;
    if (this.genres != null) {
      data['genres'] = this.genres.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['source'] = this.source;
    if (this.producers != null) {
      data['producers'] = this.producers.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['score'] = this.score;
    data['licensors'] = this.licensors;
    data['r18'] = this.r18;
    data['kids'] = this.kids;
    data['continuing'] = this.continuing;
    return data;
  }
}
```

4. This is the function that I used to fetch json data:

```
Future getdata(String season,int year) async {
    var url = baseUrl + '/season/$year/${season.toString()}';
    print('hitting url $url');
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var jsondata= jsonDecode(response.body);
  }
}
```

5. what I want is to modify the getdata function to make it map the json into the class that I created, then display it in  a listview using a futrebuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Without me seeing your json data and making sure that your model class matches up I'm assuming it all does you should be able to do the following

```
 import 'package:jikan_dart/src/model/season/anime.dart' as ac; //to avoid package conflict use 'as' then you can refer to this package using what ever keyword you've picked

List<ac.Anime> animeList = new List<ac.Anime>();
for(var item in jsonData){
    ac.Anime anime = ac.Anime.fromJson(item);
    animeList.add(item);
}
```

Ideally at this point you'd save your list in a [sqflite database](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite). (Unless you want the user to always make the api call).

In your view class you can then create a futurebuilder that call to your database to retrieve the data and display it in your listview.

```
_animeList(String season, int year){
   new Container(
    child: new FutureBuilder<List<ac.Anime>>(
              future: getdata(season, year),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ac.Anime>> snapshot) {
                  if(!snapshot.hasData){
                      return new Center(
                        child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                     }else{
                   return new ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                         return Container(
                                    child: Text('${snapshot.data.title}'),
                      ); //return whatever widget you want to use to display your data
                    }
                  }
}
```

Comment: i Am having this error: The name 'Anime' is defined in the libraries 'package:anime_app/Anime/anime_classes.dart' and 'package:jikan_dart/src/model/season/anime.dart'.
Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports.dart(ambiguous_import)

Comment: updated the answer again because I referenced the wrong package. Whenever you want to reference your anime model you'll have to use 'ac.Anime' or whatever prefix you've chosen this will tell the IDE what class should be used when referenced in your code.

Comment: you used list<Drug> for what is Drug?

Comment: nothing worked for me , can you provide me with a full code for implementing jikan api into flutter listview

Comment: that was a typo, I copied the code I use in my application, that should be list<ac.Anime>. I have no idea what jkan api is

Comment: ok no prob, post your solution, in case some one else has the same issues.